# How to find last row in mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql

I've a table something as follows

```
id                                         other_columns
1
1
1
2
2
3
1
3
```

How do I detect that row no. 7 is the last row with id value 1. Similarly row number 5 is the last row with id value 2. Row number 8 is last row with id value 3. Is it possible to achieve this using php?

Comment: order is relative, there must be some field with value 7 for this to make sense

Comment: You cannot. Rows in SQL represent unordered sets.

Comment: Do you have some other column that you can use to order them, like a date?

Comment: Yes a column date exists.

Comment: Amend your question accordingly.

Comment: See the linked question. Find the row with the maximum date grouped by ID.